# Do I have to call return true each time I use onMessage.addListener responseCallback?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have the a onMessage.addListener function like this:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (r, s, sendResponse) {
    if (r.action == "read") {
        readManga(request, function () {
            sendResponse({});
        }, true);
    }
    if (r.action == "write") {
        readManga(request, function () {
            sendResponse({});
        }, true);
    }
    if (request.action == "update") {
        $.each(request.list, function (index, val) {
            resetManga(val, function () {}, false);
        });
        saveList();
        refreshUpdate();
        sendResponse({});
    }
    if (request.action == "release") {
        releaseImplentationFromId(request.id, function (mirrorName) {
            updateMirrors(function () {
                sendResponse({
                    mirror : mirrorName
                });
            });
            return true
        });
    }
}
```

(this is an excerpt, but [it's working code](https://github.com/braiam/AMR/blob/develop/js/background.js#L602) and please ignore all the if's, I should have used case since long ago)

Each time I use the callback function `sendResponse` (again, I need to rename it, but lets ignore that) as defined [in the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage) is never used unless I have `return true` after it's execution. Is this really necessary or I just found a dirty hack and I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the expected behavior and clearly stated in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage):

> This function [`sendResponse`] becomes invalid when the event listener returns, unless you return `true` from the event listener to indicate you wish to send a response asynchronously (this will keep the message channel open to the other end until `sendResponse` is called).

Your function `updateMirrors` is apparently asynchronous: the callback function does not get executed immediately but is sent into a queue. So, you're not returning true "after" its execution, you are actually hitting `return true` before `sendResponse`.

Therefore, it's necessary to tell Chrome "expect an answer later".

Comment: So, for each callback function (all of them are async, so no worries) I need to add `return true`.

Comment: You can just do it once at the end of the `onMessage` listener, after the `if`s