# access to $http in chrome extension background js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension

I have angular working fine for the front end popup of my chrome extension but I need the background script to do an ajax request and I cannot even begin to think how I can get angular's $http there.

Specifically I will be responding with the ajax result from a call to the chrome API "chrome.runtime.sendMessage".

So currently I have my listener wired up in the background.js

```
var someData="TESTDATA";
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    sendResponse(someData);
});
```

and what I want is

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: "http://autocomplete.wunderground.com/' +
          'aq?query=" +
          'query'
  }).success(function(data) {
    sendResponse(data.RESULTS);
  }).error(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
});
```

which obviously does not work even though angular.js is in the manifest file for the background.

How can I use the angular $http object in this setup?
(I do not have an html page for the background.js)

Comment: Even though you said the angular is in your manifest file, could you please show us your manifest file?

Comment: Why do you need to use angular's `$http`? Why not just a standard XHR request?

Comment: @abraham simply consistency.

Comment: You may want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/24405235/934239

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To use $http, you must be within a controller, directive or Angular's service.**

To do it the way you're doing, you can create a `global variable`, then within a controller you should assign `$http` to the variable you created.

```
var $http2;

myApp.controller('foo', ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http){
    $http2 = $http;
});

//Now you have access to: $http2({method:...})
```

Or you can do it in a simpler way:

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.onload = function () {
    if(x.status == 200) {
        console.log(x.responseText);
        sendResponse(x.responseText);
    }
};
x.onerror = function(err) {
    console.log(err)
};
x.open('GET', 'http://autocomplete.wunderground.com/' + 'aq?query=' +  'query');
x.send()
```

Comment: Yep trying to use angular as library was a really bad Idea I will just use standard AJAX

Answer (score 1):

To use the $http provider without instantiating any controllers, use the following:

```
var $http = angular.injector(['ng']).get("$http");
```

Comment: Although I had settled on the AJAX route I did go back and try your suggestion and it works flawlessly.